# android:appCategory in Android O. Which values?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-8.0-oreo

Android O introduces the concept of app categories. These categories are used to cluster together apps of similar purpose or function. The developer declares this in the `AndroidManifest.xml` using `android:appCategory` according to the [Android O Features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#category) documentation.

What the documentation isn't clear on is ***what values can this attribute be?*** I'm guessing it will be a discrete set of values rather than any string.

Comment: Mostly the list of string that you can find in google play console while publishing your app.

Comment: That does not seem to be documented. I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37135431) about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Upon installing Android Studio 2.4 (Preview 4) and amending the `AndroidManifest.xml`, the context revealed...

[image]

As this is a preview release of the environment, the above may not be finalised and correct. So we still need proper documentation as to how this attribute should be used.

Comment: Values are now detailed on the developers page too: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#appCategory

Comment: Usage `android:appCategory` prior to Android 8 is ignored? Can i safely use in manifest for Android 7 for example?

Comment: _Can i safely use in manifest for Android 7 for example?_ From Android Studio: The application will simply ignore the attribute.